# Error to copy one value from a checkbox to another checkbox

Tags: formula-field, checkbox

I have a field OBS approved(checkbox) on lead object. I want to carry this value on another field on a custom object. I have created a formulae field on the custom object return type as checkbox.

I have using the formulae Lead__r.OBS_Approved__c but I get the error as Error: Field Lead__r does not exist. Check spelling.

Am I doing anything wrong. Please help.

Should I use any other syntax.

Comment: Do you have a lookup from the custom object to the Lead object? If so, what is the name of the field?

Comment: your syntax is fine. You need the lookup relationship in place before it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clearly you are getting this error because that Lead__r does not exist in your system.
I implemented the same in my dev org. Instead writing field in formula you just select field it from INSET FIELD button and rest will work like a charm.
See the below image, i created lookup in custom object Distributor n formula field also in distributor as you are doing.

[image: demo]